# regex php - find value in div with specific ID

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

How can i do to find the content of this div with `preg_match()`?

The link to my page can be found [here](http://www.faucet.com/kraus-c-gv-100-12mm-1005-chrome-bathroom-combo-16-1-2-clear-glass-vessel-bathroom-sink-with-vessel-faucet/f1870941).

I want get the product value of this page. I did something like this but i can't get nothing:

```
if (!preg_match("<div id=\"productPrice\">(.*)<\/div>/si", $data, $dealer_price)) 
    return;
```

I am also trying the following:

```
if (!preg_match("<div class=\"price\">(.*)<\/div>/si", $data, $dealer_price)) 
    return;
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: This is *much* easier to do by parsing the DOM

Comment: but i want use preg_match function

Comment: You're perfectly welcome to eat soup with a fork

Comment: It is not only easier to use DOM, it is also safer and more reliable. Like your preg won't match `<div     id=\"productPrice\">` ? Or `<div class="some" id=\'productPrice\'>`

Comment: i am also using <div class="some" id=\'productPrice\'> but cant work. my page link is added in question

Comment: May I refer you to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few reasons your regular expression is not working as you expect.

1. You supply no delimiter in the beginning of your expression.
2. There is an attribute after your div `@id` attribute.
3. `*` is a [**greedy**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html) operator, you should use `*?` to return a non-greedy match.
4. If you want the value you need to return your captured group.

To fix your regular expression:

```
preg_match('~<div id="productPrice"[^>]*>(.*?)</div>~si', $data, $dealer_price);
echo trim($dealer_price[1]); //=> "$249.95"
```

Use [`DOM`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to grab the product value from your data, not regular expression.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($data);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$node  = $xpath->query("//div[@id='productPrice']")->item(0);
echo trim($node->nodeValue); //=> "$249.95"
```

Comment: +1 The quantifier between tags must be lazy. Since you have the id (that is unique) no need to use xpath, use directly getElementById

Comment: @hwnd: it's an eval.in bug, works well on my server.

Answer (score 0):

The regexes in `preg` need to be enclosed in delimiters, such as `~` or `/` etc. Also, you need to use lazy matching in your expression:

```
preg_match( "@<div id=\"productPrice\">(.*)</div>@siU", $data, $dealer_price )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $data = '<body><div id="productPrice">12.20</div></body>';
  if(!preg_match('/<div id="productPrice">(.*)<\/div>/si', $data, $dealer_price)) return;

  $dealer_price = $dealer_price[0];
  echo $dealer_price;
?>
```

hope this helps..